# C# Download Resources From URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, browser, download

I've been working on a browser on c# where I need to download all files from the URL. The problem is that not all files are downloaded.

I suspect there may be a problem with my implementation of my function. Could someone help me identify what the problem might be and suggest a solution?

Here's a snippet of the code where I download files:

```
public class ResourceManager
{
    private readonly string _dataPath;

    public ResourceManager(string dataPath)
    {
        this._dataPath = dataPath;
    }   
    private Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> _data = new();

    private static bool DownloadResource(string url, string path)
    {
        using var client = new HttpClient();
        using var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
        using var response = client.Send(request);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            using var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
            response.Content.CopyToAsync(fs);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            //Console.Error.WriteLine($"Bad Url: {url}"); 
            return false;
        }
        
    }

    public bool GetResource(string url, out string fileName)
    {
        var myUri = new Uri(url);
        var host = myUri.Host;
        var path = myUri.AbsolutePath;

        if (!_data.ContainsKey(host))
        {
            _data.Add(host, new Dictionary<string, string>());
        }

        _data[host].TryGetValue(path, out fileName);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName) && File.Exists(fileName)) return true;
        
        fileName = Path.Combine(_dataPath, $"{host}__{Util.ComputeHash(path)}");
        if (DownloadResource(url, fileName))
        {
            _data[host].Add(path, fileName);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            fileName = null;
            return false;
        }
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with [using a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193).  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: `StreamCopyToAsync` (as the name already implies) is an asynchronous method. While you can call it that way, you're never ever *(a)waiting* for its result. You should make yourself familiar with `async` and `await` when fetching data from a URL.

Answer (score 0):

Httpclient cannot get all resources from the URL. I suggest you try "httrack" https://www.httrack.com/page/2/#google_vignette which crawl the website resources to local folder. You could browse the website offline after crawling.